# Can't use unichr in Python 3.1

Tags: python, unicode, string

I've been looking through the **Python Cookbook (2nd Edition)** to learn how to process strings and characters.

I wanted to try converting a number into its Unicode equivalent. So I tried using the [built-in function called '**unichr**'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr), which, according to the Cookbook, goes something like:

```
>>> print repr(unichr(8224))
```

... and will output:

```
u'\u2020'
```

However, the code failed. I thought it had something to do with **print** (because Python 3 uses print() instead of print ""), but that didn't work out as well. I tried several variations to the code, and it still failed. At long last, I just typed a simple line:

```
unichr(10000)
```

To my surprise, this error message kept popping up, no matter what value I put into the above function:

```
 NameError: name 'unichr' is not defined
```

What could be the problem? Is there some specific module that I'm supposed to import?

Comment: Just a tip: you could and should have mentioned the error message right after "the code failed."  Always note the error message Python gives (and the *exact* error message, not from memory), and mention it early.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will definitely keep it mind.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In Python 3, you just use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> chr(10000)
'✐'
```

Answer (score 24):

In Python 3, there's no difference between unicode and normal strings anymore. Only between unicode strings and binary data. So the developers finally removed the `unichr` function in favor of a common `chr` which now does what the old `unichr` did. See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: There are still two string-ish types. What 2.x calls `unicode`, 3.x calls `str` (with trivial changes). What 2.x calls `str`, 3.x calls `bytes` (with moderate changes).

Answer (score 7):

In case you need to run in both python 2 and python 3, you can use this common syntax
(the unused syntax would point to the new one)

```
try:
    unichr
except NameError:
    unichr = chr
```

Answer (score 7):

As suggestted by [this](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#unichr) is a better way to do it for it is compatible for both 2 and 3:

```
# Python 2 and 3:
from builtins import chr
assert chr(8364) == '€'
```

And you may need `pip install future` incase some error occures.

Answer (score 6):

Python 3.x doesn't have a special Unicode string type/class.  Every string is a Unicode string.  So... I'd try `chr`.  Should give you what `unichr` did pre-3.x.  Can't test, sadly.