# can someone convert this python 2 code to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

## a table structure to hold the different punctuation used

tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode)
                      if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))

Comment: Please update your question with more details about your problem, add your codes plus its output and your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one:

```
import unicodedata

tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P'))
```

Some explanation:

[Why is there no xrange function in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014310/why-is-there-no-xrange-function-in-python3)

[Can't use unichr in Python 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352018/cant-use-unichr-in-python-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
import unicodedata
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P'))
```

In python3 there is no `unichr`, it becomes `chr`. Also, there is no `xrange` it becomes `range`.